# How do I send all form data from one view to another with sessions in Django

Tags: django, session, django-views, django-forms

So I already know how to send and receive one value from InputWebView to DisplayWebView but I need to send all values from my form and receive it on the other side to process further. How do I do that?

```
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{ form.web_input }}
<input type="submit">
</form/>


def InputWebView(requests):

    form = WebInputForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['web_input'] = request.POST['web_input']
            return redirect('add_web')


def DisplayWebView(request):
    var = request.session.get('web_input')
```

Comment: You can store form values with cookies

Comment: If you want to use sessions look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/) it is given that default JSON serializer can't handle all types try changing to Pickle serializer or write your own to handle the form